# iOS Objective-C block callback issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to use pure code to create UI practice block pass value between viewController. But the callback block didn't work. The NSLog method didn't print anything on debug area. Here's the code. Give me some tips, thank you.

VC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
    @property (copy, nonatomic) void (^callBack)(NSString *text);
@end
```

VC.m

```
- (UITextField *)textField {
    if (!_textField) {
        _textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        _textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return _textField;
}

- (UIButton *)button {
    if (!_button) {
        _button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        _button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return _button;
}

- (void)setupUI {
    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button];

    [self.textField mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.mas_equalTo(200);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(50);
        make.centerX.mas_equalTo(self.view.mas_centerX);
        make.centerY.mas_equalTo(self.view);
    }];

    [self.button mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.mas_equalTo(200);
        make.height.mas_equalTo(50);
        make.centerX.mas_equalTo(self.view);
        make.centerY.mas_equalTo(self.view).offset(100);
    }];
}

- (void)buttonAction {

    NSString *str = self.textField.text;
    if (self.callBack != nil) {
        self.callBack(str);
        NSLog(@"This statement didnt print in log");
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupUI];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

---

update code

VC2.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

            self.callBack = ^(NSString *text){

            };
    }
- (void)buttonAction {

    if (self.callBack) {
        NSLog(@"It worked on debug area %@", self.textField.text);
        self.callBack(self.textField.text);
    }
    self.textField.text = @"";
}
```

VC1.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _secondVc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    _secondVc.callBack = ^(NSString *str){

    };
    [self setupUI];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if (_secondVc.callBack != nil) {
        NSLog(@"It wrked on debug screen");
        _secondVc.callBack = ^(NSString *str){
            NSLog(@"It didn't worked on debug screen");
            //I want set my label.text = str;
        };
};
```

}

Comment: Your `callBack` is nil to begin with. I suggest you to look into this example to know more about objective-C blocks. http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/

Comment: thx for your link, i have  fixed it .Do you have any other block and swift closure tutorial link or video?

Comment: I initial the callback block in second viewDidLoad.The secondViewController worked, but i cant call it from firstViewController.How to call it in firstVC.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is that you property

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^callBack)(NSString *text);
```

is empty. Try to put breakpoint in `buttonAction` method and look at the property.

Answer (score 0):

As Sander and KrishnaCA mentioned your `callBack` is nil. I would suggest you create a definition of the block like this:

```
typedef void(^TextBlock)(NSString *text);
```

Then change your property to:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) TextBlock callBack;
```

Create a copy of the block in your first view controller:

```
@interface FirstViewController()

@property (copy, nonatomic) TextBlock firstViewControllerCallBack;

@end
```

Initialize the callback copy (i.e. in viewDidLoad)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.firstViewControllerCallBack = ^(NSString *text){
        NSLog(@"Second view controller's button tapped!");
    };
}
```

Assign the callback to the second view controller right before presenting/pushing it:

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondVC.callBack = self.firstViewControllerCallBack; // Assign the callback
// ... Presenting the view controller
```

Clean up the completion block after you done with it (i.e. in viewWillDisappear):

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.firstViewControllerCallBack = nil;
}
```

Comment: Fallow your steps the NSLog(@"Second view controller's button tapped!"); didn't work,why- -

Comment: I looked at your updated code, you are assigning a new callback every time viewWillAppear in VC2.m, which means the callback you assigned to the first view controller will be overwritten. If you put the NSLog(@"Second view controller's button tapped!");  in your second view controller's viewWillAppear's callBack it should print the message. BTW, you also missing [super viewWillAppear]; in your VC2.m

Comment: I  have read some book about block and already done with it, any way thx for your help.